# Difference Boolean Troubleshooting

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I figured I would start by trying something basic, involving three floors, and a pair of stairs. For the top two floors, some sort of hole needs to be created in the floors to allow passage. I did this with a cube mesh and the difference boolean operator. The first floor worked. The second did not.

The screenshots below can provide a little extra detail. In the second half, you can see the operator worked correctly. The floor was cut in to correctly and the inner faces are in place. In the first half of the screenshot, you can see where it did not work properly. This is a view from inside the cut. The inner faces were created when the operator was applied, but the top and bottom faces were never removed.

[image]

I'd like to think that I recreated the steps exactly with both applying the operators, as well as creating the cube meshes that make up each floor, but clearly something went wrong along the way. The question is, what is it? And how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Problems with Booleans are always the same: Avoid coplanar surfaces avoid coinciding faces, use only closed watertight meshes, use only manifold geometries, check both objects normals, make sure they are consistent. Other than that it's impossible to help you with this little info, search this site for the hundreds of questions about booleans and check the all answers there. Also for the long run boolean operations are not really a sustainable or reliable modelling method for meshes.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the majority of the terms you've listed, but I think the problem lied in the fact that the object used to cut the hole was unnoticeably protruding from the side of the floor. Adjusting the object to be within the floor's boundaries fixed it, but why is this a requirement for the modifier to work in the first place?